# Can I fast-fail a test series?

Tags: quick-nimble

I have a set of tests that crash the whole test suite if a given situation arises. Moreover, that situation is already a failure for the suite.

Rather than crash, I'd rather test if the condition is true during the setup of the series, and fast-abort it with a failure.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can fail a test at anytime with:

```
fail("And here you give the reason for the failure")
```